# How to search through multiple properties in a sorted list with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash

I have a data set with people's first names and last names and I want users to be able to search through these with Vue 2.

So far, I managed to sort the list first by first name, then by last name using Lodash and I also managed to categorize them by type. Now I want to filter/search (I don't know the correct word) the array and only show people of whom (part of) the first or last name or both match the input field's content.

A vanilla JS solution would be as much appreciated as a Lodash solution!

```
props: {
  people: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
},

data: function(){
  return {
    filter: '',
    people:[{
      "FirstName" : "Stefan",
      "LastName" : "Braun",
      "Type" : "EN",
    },
    {
      "FirstName" : "Jenny",
      "LastName" : "Smith",
      "Type" : "VO",
    },
    {
      "FirstName" : "Susan",
      "LastName" : "Jones",
      "Type" : "EN",
    }]
  }
}

methods: {

  matchingType: function (people, type) {
    people = this.alphabeticallyOrdered(this.searchFiltered(people))

    return people.filter(function (person) {
      return person.Type == type
    })
  },

  alphabeticallyOrdered: function(arr){
    return _.orderBy(arr, ['FirstName', 'LastName'])
  },

  searchFiltered: function(arr){
    filter = this.filter
    return _.some(arr, _.unary(_.partialRight(_.includes, this.filter)));
  }
},

template: `
  <div>
    <input type="text" model="filter"></input>
    <div v-for="type in types" class="type" :class="type.short">
      <h2 class="type-name">{{type.long}}</h2>
      <div class="people">
        <div v-for="person in matchingType(people, type.short)" class="person">
          <div class="personal-details">
            <p class="h2">{{person.FirstName}}</p>
            <p class="h4">{{person.LastName}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you would handle this using a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Here is an example. I'm eliminating a lot of the extra code in your example as there are parts I cannot replicate without knowing exactly what you are doing (you don't post the fill code for the component), but in essence, you would write a computed property like the following and iterate over that in your template.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  data:{
     people:[{
      "FirstName" : "Stefan",
      "LastName" : "Braun",
      "Type" : "EN",
    },
    {
      "FirstName" : "Jenny",
      "LastName" : "Smith",
      "Type" : "VO",
    },
    {
      "FirstName" : "Susan",
      "LastName" : "Jones",
      "Type" : "EN",
    }],
    filterText: null
  },
  computed:{
    filteredPeople(){
      // If there is no filter text, just return everyone
      if (!this.filterText) return this.people
      
      // Convert the search text to lower case
      let searchText = this.filterText.toLowerCase()
      
      // Use the standard javascript filter method of arrays
      // to return only people whose first name or last name
      // includes the search text
      return this.people.filter(p => {
        // if IE support is required and not pre-compiling,
        // use indexOf instead of includes
        return p.FirstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
        p.LastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)  
      })
    }
    
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="filterText">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="person in filteredPeople">
      {{person.FirstName}}  {{person.LastName}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @kslstn How is type selected? Dropdown?

Comment: Thank you, Bert. I tried this, but as the list has to be filtered by the input text *and* by type, I don't get it to work: https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/pdXXvO

I've tried moving the computed matchingPeople to methods, but then it doesn't get updated when the input field text is changed by the user: https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/JOQeEY

Comment: Sorry about submitting the previous comment before I was finished! To answer your question: the type is selected in v-for: first a list of engineers is shown, then a list of designers.

Comment: I hope the codepens help, they are more generalized examples of what I want to achieve.

Comment: @kslstn You say you want to filter by type, but is it really that you just want to list by type?

Comment: I guess so! What I want to do is show an overview of people. Each person belongs to a group (type), e.g. Engineers and on the page the people are categorized under these groups. Within the groups they have to be alphabetically sorted.  Then there is the search field that lets users filter by name.

Comment: I think you're hinting towards the idea that I could split up the data array with all people into smaller arrays for each group at initialization. Then I could probably dynamically filter those groups with your solution. Although actually, no: then I'd need a computed property for each of the types and have the same issue.

Comment: @kslstn Something like this then https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ZadgGb?editors=1010

Comment: Yes, almost there! The only thing that is not right yet, is that the order of the group changes depending on the search text (try entering "s" and see they are flipped). I tried to fix that by adding a position property and ordering by that property in the groupedPeople computed variable, but that broke it: https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/KyOPxZ?editors=1010

Comment: @kslstn Alright, this should do it. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/OOKJzQ?editors=1010

Comment: YES! Thank you for your support and even throwing a non-Lodash solution in the mix.